# How to print many graphical objects in a loop?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I have to print a lot of barcodes. How can I do it in a loop, if I use this code block to print a single barcode:

```
    p.PrintPage += delegate(object sender1, PrintPageEventArgs e1) {
                    e1.Graphics.DrawString("TITLE", new Font("Univers 55", 6), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), new RectangleF(titleX, titleY, p.DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea.Width, p.DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea.Height));
                    e1.Graphics.DrawString(s, new Font("Barcode", 24), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), new RectangleF(codeX, codeY, p.DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea.Width, p.DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea.Height));
                    e1.Graphics.DrawString(test, new Font("Univers 55", 8), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), new RectangleF(numberX, numberY, p.DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea.Width, p.DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea.Height));
```

};

**titleX**, **titleY**, **codeX**, **codeY**, **numberX**, **numberY** are variables which store the position of the three parts of each barcode object (title, stripes and number), they should alter themselves in a loop.

Comment: Put it in a function and call the function in a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to print multiple barcodes on a single page, nothing is stopping you from putting those in a loop. I would move the code to a separate method though, instead of an "inline delegate", to keep it clean:

```
p.PrintPage += PrintPage;
...
private void PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfBarcodes; i++)
    {
        int titleY = i * titleYdistance + titleYoffset;
        // etc.

        e.Graphics.DrawString(...);
        // etc.
    }
}
```

If you have more than what would fit on a single page, the `PrintPageEventArgs` class has a [`HasMorePages`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printpageeventargs.hasmorepages(v=vs.110).aspx) property. The event method is called as long as you keep setting this property to `true`, allowing you to print different barcodes for each page.

Comment: Thanks! I'm still trying it : )

Comment: The `HasMorePages` property doesn't function. Where should I set it?

Comment: @relapse You don't "just set it" you need to figure out if you can fit everything on a single page, if it can't you set it to `true` and break out of the loop early. This will cause the function to get called again for the 2nd page. You repeat that process till you run out of barcodes to print then you set it false. See [How to: Print a Multi-Page Text File in Windows Forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cwbe712d(v=vs.110).aspx) for a example of how it works, intead of `i` being `0` every time you need to remember the last `i` you did and use that + 1 as the starting point.

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain The variable which controls the executing of the handle should be a class one in order not to lose its value when the handle is called again.